# get items 2 by 2 from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, filter

What is the most elegant way to obtain items 2 by 2 from a list ?

```
from:
my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']

to:
res_list = ['I swear', 'swear I', 'I googled', 'googled first']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say a standard case for `zip`:

```
def pairs(i):
    return list(zip(i, i[1:]))

my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']
res_list = pairs(my_list)
print(res_list)
# [('I', 'swear'), ('swear', 'I'), ('I', 'googled'), ('googled', 'first')]
print([' '.join(a) for a in res_list])
# ['I swear', 'swear I', 'I googled', 'googled first']
```

Just for completeness's sake, the same with arbitrary window width:

```
def window(i, n = 2):
    return list(zip(*(i[p:] for p in range(n))))
```

Comment: Choice was hard with the answer of unutbu :)

Comment: @kollo And both are viable. His is more general for windows of width `n` and mine for your specific case. Nevertheless you can also use `zip` for arbitrary width windows.

Answer (score 5):

```
def window(seq, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the sequence
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...
    """
    for i in xrange(len(seq)-n+1):
        yield tuple(seq[i:i+n])

my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']
res_list = [' '.join(group) for group in window(my_list, 2)]
print(res_list)
# ['I swear', 'swear I', 'I googled', 'googled first']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def pairwise( iterable, n=2 ):
    from itertools import tee, izip, islice
    return izip(*(islice(it,pos,None) for pos,it in enumerate(tee(iterable, n))))

my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']

print list(pairwise(my_list))
#[('I', 'swear'), ('swear', 'I'), ('I', 'googled'), ('googled', 'first')]
```

Comment: Three imports and four function calls for which can be achieved without imports and one call to `zip`... I am not sure about short and efficient.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Our solutions would fail if the input were an infinite iterator, whereas M4rtini's itertool solution would return an infinite iterator.

Comment: @unutbu Thank you. Didn't take into consideration this. Nevertheless, if we don't convert it into a list and just return a `zip` object (in my case) or just `yield` (in your case) I don't see the problem for infinite iterators.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Try our solutions with input `itertools.count()`. Mine would fail (raise TypeError) on `len(seq)`. Yours would raise a TypeError on `i[1:]`. M4rtini's solution also requires less memory (if the input were finite but huge) since the input is never duplicated. My solution may require even less memory than M4rtini's since `tee` requires some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A neat little one-liner in the form of a generator expression:

```
>>> my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']
>>> res_list = (' '.join((x, y)) for x, y in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))
>>> list(res_list)
['I swear', 'swear I', 'I googled', 'googled first']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['I', 'swear', 'I', 'googled', 'first']

def two_words(my_list):
   i=0
   words=[]
   for word in my_list:
    
        words.append(word)
        if i%2:
            yield (" ".join(words))
            words.clear()
        i+=1
    if len(words)>0:
        yield (" ".join(words))
    
print(list(two_words(my_list)))
```

output:

```
 ['I swear', 'I googled', 'first']
```